# Doctrine QueryBuilder: having / where error using alias

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

i have Symfony 2.5.1.

**EntityRepository**

```
class TbActivityRepository extends EntityRepository
    {   
        public function findSchoolActivities($school_id)
        {
                $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
                $qb->select("a.name, a.datefrom, a.dateto, a.description, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p1.school) 
                                    FROM DomestosAdminBundle:TbPhoto p1 
                                WHERE p1.activity = a.id) AS active_schools,
                            CASE 
                                WHEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() >= a.datefrom AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() <= a.dateto THEN 'open'
                                WHEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() > a.dateto THEN 'close'
                                ELSE 'new'
                            END AS actual_status")
                   ->from("DomestosAdminBundle:TbActivity", "a")
                   ->leftJoin("a.photo", "p")
                   ->where("p.school = :id")
                   ->setParameter("id", $school_id);

                return $qb;
        }
```

in **controller** I call

```
$this->qb = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('DomestosAdminBundle:TbActivity')
                ->findSchoolActivities($school_id);
```

and after

```
public function ajaxTable($flag = false){
        if ( isset( $this->get['iDisplayStart'] ) && $this->get['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' ){
            $this->qb->setFirstResult( (int)$this->get['iDisplayStart'] )
                ->setMaxResults( (int)$this->get['iDisplayLength'] );
        }

        /*
        * Ordering
        */
        if ( isset( $this->get['iSortCol_0'] ) ){
            for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $this->get['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ ){
                if ( $this->get[ 'bSortable_'.intval($this->get['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" ){
                    $this->qb->orderBy($this->aColumns[ (int)$this->get['iSortCol_'.$i] ], $this->get['sSortDir_'.$i]);
                }
            }
        }

        /*
        * Filtering
        */
        if ( isset($this->get['sSearch']) && $this->get['sSearch'] != '' ){ // main search
            $aLikeWhere = array();
            $aLikeHaving = array();
            for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($this->aColumns) ; $i++ ){
                if ( isset($this->get['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $this->get['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" ){
                    if($this->alias[$i] != null) {
                        $aLikeWhere[] = $this->qb->expr()->like($this->aColumns[$i], '\'%'. $this->get['sSearch'] .'%\'');
                    } else {
                        $aLikeHaving[] = $this->qb->expr()->like($this->aColumns[$i], '\'%'. $this->get['sSearch'] .'%\'');
                    }
                }
            }
            if(count($aLikeWhere) > 0) $this->qb->andWhere(new Expr\Orx($aLikeWhere));
            else unset($aLikeWhere);
            if(count($aLikeHaving) > 0) $this->qb->andHaving(new Expr\Orx($aLikeHaving));
            else unset($aLikeHaving);
.....
$rResult = $this->ajaxTable(true)->getArrayResult();
```

And my **error** is:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 756: Error: Expected '.' or '(', got 'active_schools'
500 Internal Server Error - QueryException
1 linked Exception:
QueryException »

[2/2] QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 756: Error: Expected '.' or '(', got 'active_schools'   +

[1/2] QueryException: SELECT a.name, a.datefrom, a.dateto, a.description, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p1.school) 
FROM DomestosAdminBundle:TbPhoto p1 
WHERE p1.activity = a.id) AS active_schools,
CASE 
WHEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() >= a.datefrom AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() <= a.dateto THEN 'open'
WHEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() > a.dateto THEN 'close'
ELSE 'new'
END AS actual_status FROM DomestosAdminBundle:TbActivity a LEFT JOIN a.photo p WHERE p.school = :id AND (a.name LIKE '%3%' OR a.datefrom LIKE '%3%' OR a.dateto LIKE '%3%' OR a.description LIKE '%3%') HAVING active_schools LIKE '%3%' OR actual_status LIKE '%3%' ORDER BY a.name asc   +
```

I tried it without *having*, only with *where* clausule and returned it also an error.
I read the *db alias *must call through *having*. In my MySQL database it works. But not here. 
Do you know anyone advise me to solve this problem?

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

Doctrine build queries using DQL (and not SQL) because it supports all kinds of database software (SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.) therefore you are limited to a certain set of functionalities.

You will want to generate a SQL query using the `NativeQuery` class, you can find more information in [the doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html)

Here are some directions (which I didn't test but should work according to the documentation):

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

class TbActivityRepository extends EntityRepository
{   
    public function findSchoolActivities($school_id)
    {
        $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();

        $query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery('SELECT * FROM table WHERE schoolId = ?', $rsm);
        $query->setParameter(1, $school_id);

        return $query->getResult();
    }
}
```

You will want to check the [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) if you need more than the example above. It's worth noting that once you make native queries your app will be bound to a specific database software.